# Intersection or Solve 

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, intersection, solution

Consider the Following :

```
daList = {{541, 0.0593368}, {550, 0.298352}, {560, 0.72619}, {570,0.734982}, 
          {580, 1.46149}, {590, 2.31119}, {600, 3.31509}}
```

Each sublist represent an {x,y} coordinate.

I need to find the x value for which the Y is equal to 1. Roughly 575 with the eye.

```
ListPlot[daList, 
        Joined -> True, 
        Epilog ->{Thick, Line[{{0, 1}, {600, 1}}]}]
```

+Help from PPT  for the Red parts to illustrate the question :

[image]

Could interpolate till I find 1 but I want to know if there exist a function for this in Mathematica.

Either a computation. Find the X for which y = 1.
Or maybe a graphical one in which line intersection x coordinate is reported on the x-axis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f = Interpolation[daList];
r = FindRoot[Evaluate[f][x] - 1, {x, 570, 541, 600}]
Show[Plot[{f[x], 1}, {x, 541, 600}], Graphics@Line[{{x, 0}, {x, 1}}] /. r]
```

[image]

**Edit**

With legend:

```
f = Interpolation[daList];
r = FindRoot[Evaluate[f][x] - 1, {x, 570, 541, 600}]
Show[Plot[{f[x], 1}, {x, 541, 600}, PlotRangePadding -> 1, Frame -> True,
      Axes ->   False, 
      Epilog -> Inset[Framed[Style[x /. r, Medium, Bold, Red], 
                      Background -> LightYellow], 
                {x, 0} /. r]], 
     Graphics[Line[{{x, -1}, {x, 1}}] /. r]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Interpolation` and flip the `x` and `y` coordinates to return an `InterpolatingFunction` that takes `y` arguments. Assuming you want linear interpolation, here's how:

```
f = Interpolation[daList ~Reverse~ 2, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
f[1]

Out[1]=573.648
```

Comment: This question sat for 15 minutes, then BAM, both of you beat me in the time it took to type.

Comment: Well, seeing as the first answer was posted well before the others, we won't be needing a duel this time :D

Comment: No duel, you are clearly faster.  But, I do prefer using `Reverse`.  If I may edit your answer with this change, I will delete mine.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard & yoda does this work for `daList = Table[{x, x^3 + 5 x^2}, {x, -6, 3, .1}];` ?

Comment: @belisarius he said "the value" not "the values" -- it seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @Mr. What value does this yield for my daList?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, you may edit it to use `Reverse`. I used an explicit reversal using `Part`, as I figured it'll be faster than `Reverse`. It indeed is, but not significant enough to make me want to stick with it.

Comment: @belisarius No, it's not a robust solution in the multivalued case. It returns an error _only_ if the `y` values in the list are duplicated exactly. If it's off even slightly due to sampling/floating point issues, it does not complain and returns an incorrect result. For example, try your `daList` above with `x` from `-4.5` to `3`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution based on line intersections with linear interpolation.  It will find all crossings.

```
crossing[y_][ln : {{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := 
 Quiet[(x1 y - x2 y - Det@ln)/(y1 - y2)] // 
  If[Sort[{x1, #, x2}][[2]] == #, #, Sequence @@ {}] &

crossing[1] /@ Partition[daList, 2, 1]
```

```
{573.648}
```

---

Multiple crossings:

```
points = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 10, 0.2}];

ListLinePlot[{points, {{0, 0.2}, {10, 0.2}}}]
```

[image]

```
crossing[0.2] /@ Partition[points, 2, 1]
```

```
{0.201395, 2.93926, 6.48559, 9.22311}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have a quick and rough answer without programming you could also select the graph and press the period (.) key. You'll get a cross-hair cursor and a tooltip providing you with the coordinates of your cross-hair, like this:

[image]
(cross-hairs don't stick in a screendump). Note this equals Mr.Wizards' result, which differs slightly from belisarius' one. This is because belisarius is using `Interpolation` with the default setting of `InterpolationOrder` (3). If you use `InterpolationOrder -> 1` all answers agree.